# Is there a library for reading maven2/3 pom xml files?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-3

I would like to read a pom.xml in Java code. I wonder if there is a library for that, so I can have an iterator for different sections, e.g., dependenes, plugins, etc. I want to avoid to build a parser by hand.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can try [MavenXpp3Reader](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/reference/maven-model/3.0.2/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/io/xpp3/MavenXpp3Reader.html) which is part of [maven-model](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.2/maven-model/index.html). Sample code:

```
MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
Model model = reader.read(new FileReader(mypom));
```

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.2/maven-model/apidocs/index.html 
This url doesn't work anymore

Comment: it works like a charm, the maven dependency is   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.2</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 37):

Firstly, I'm assuming you are not already running inside a Maven plugin, as there are easier ways to achieve that with the available APIs there.

The `MavenXpp3Reader` solution posted earlier will allow you to read the POM easily, however does not take into account inheritance of the parent and interpolation of expressions.

For that, you would need to use the [ModelBuilder](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.2/maven-model-builder/apidocs/index.html) class.

Use of this is quite simple, for example from [Archiva](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/archiva/trunk/archiva-modules/plugins/maven2-repository/src/main/java/org/apache/archiva/metadata/repository/storage/maven2/Maven2RepositoryStorage.java?revision=1053542&view=markup) is this code fragment:

```
ModelBuildingRequest req = new DefaultModelBuildingRequest();
req.setProcessPlugins( false );
req.setPomFile( file );
req.setModelResolver( new RepositoryModelResolver( basedir, pathTranslator ) );
req.setValidationLevel( ModelBuildingRequest.VALIDATION_LEVEL_MINIMAL );

Model model;
try
{
    model = builder.build( req ).getEffectiveModel();
}
catch ( ModelBuildingException e )
{
     ...
}
```

You must do two things to run this though:

1. instantiate and wire an instance of `ModelBuilder` including its private fields
2. use one of Maven's resolvers for finding the parent POMs, or write your own (as is the case in the above snippet)

How best to do that depends on the DI framework you are already using, or whether you want to just embed Maven's default container.

Comment: As far as I understand, this is the Maven 3 way of doing it. What would be the Maven 2.2.x approach, could you please show us? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the libraries are compatible, so I'd recommend using the maven 3 libraries for embedding regardless. If you really need to use the Maven 2 libraries, you can find an example here: https://github.com/brettporter/centrepoint/blob/master/centrepoint/modules/maven-importer/src/main/java/com/effectivemaven/centrepoint/maven/repository/CentralRepositoryService.java

Comment: @BrettPorter I am not running in a Maven Plugin and I have problems with the RepositoryModelResolver. How can I make that work outside a maven plugin?

Comment: what sort of problems are you having with the resolver? I'd have expected the builder to the be hard one to instantiate. (Feel free to post a new question and point to it...)

Comment: @BrettPorter Now I am running inside a maven plugin and still have problems. RepositoryModelResolver does not exist in maven-core 3.0.5. And I have problems setting the ModelResolver. Getting every time the failure message "cannot be accessed from outside package". Any idea?

Comment: @BrettPorter If I am running in a maven plugin, why I need to set the ModelResolver manually? Should it not be possible to fetch it from system?

Comment: Having the same problem as Robert: I can't find a resolver to pass into setModelResolver(). I'm running in a Mojo, so I've got the RepositorySystem and the RepositorySystemSession.  My Mojo resolved the dependency POM files fine using Aether.  Now I want to parse these POM files.  All I seem to be missing is the resolver.

Comment: @RobertReiz Raised a [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27383357/how-do-i-instantiate-mavenresolver-for-modelbuilder-usage), appreciate it if you can shed a light.

Comment: small correction, MavenXpp3Reader parses also the parent information, see here https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=swissquote/carnotzet/carnotzet-master/core/src/main/java/com/github/swissquote/carnotzet/core/maven/CarnotzetModuleCoordinates.java  an example using the getParent() method

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what you're trying to achieve. If you just want to treat it as an XML with embedded XML files, go with suggestions already offered.

If you are looking to implement some form of Maven functionality into your app, you could try the new [aether](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/AETHER/Home) library. I haven't used it, but it looks simple enough to integrate and should offer Maven functionality with little effort on your part.

BTW, this library is a Maven 3 lib, not Maven 2 (as specified in your tag). Don't know if that makes much difference to you

Comment: Wow, zombie topic. Anyway, as I said, depends on what you're trying to do. If just parsing the config externally to maven, I'd either use a normal XML parser. If you're writing a plugin, I'd imagine you can, but there may be newer libraries available (I've been out of Maven dev for a while now). You could look at some of the plugin docs - http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/

PS. I noticed the link to aether no longer works new link is - http://www.eclipse.org/aether/