# Maven `help:effective-pom` only generating for a single project, not all projects

Tags: java, maven

I want to generate an effective pom for all the subprojects in a multi-module build.

The `help:effective-pom` documentation [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/usage.html#The_help:effective-pom_Goal) states

> It will iterate over all projects in the current build session, printing the effective POM for each

I'm running `mvn help:effective-pom` in the root directory of [this maven project](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-maven-transform/tree/master/example/maven-root) and it's only generating for the root and not for the subprojects.

Why isn't the effective pom being generated for all projects. Note: I have another real world maven project where `mvn help:effective-pom` is correctly generating a `<projects>` tag with nested `<project>` for each submodule. I am unsure why it is not working for [this maven project](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-maven-transform/tree/master/example/maven-root)

Here is the effective pom generated

```
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Generated by Maven Help Plugin on 2017-11-12T09:56:26                  -->
<!-- See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/                -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Effective POM for project                                              -->
<!-- 'org.gradle.test.performance:project:pom:1.0'                          -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.gradle.test.performance</groupId>
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>project0</module>
    <module>project1</module>
    <module>project2</module>
    <module>project3</module>
    <module>project4</module>
    <module>project5</module>
    <module>project6</module>
    <module>project7</module>
    <module>project8</module>
    <module>project9</module>
  </modules>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\code\gradle-maven-transform\example\smallJavaMultiProject\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\code\gradle-maven-transform\example\smallJavaMultiProject\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>C:\code\gradle-maven-transform\example\smallJavaMultiProject\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>C:\code\gradle-maven-transform\example\smallJavaMultiProject\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>C:\code\gradle-maven-transform\example\smallJavaMultiProject\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>C:\code\gradle-maven-transform\example\smallJavaMultiProject\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>C:\code\gradle-maven-transform\example\smallJavaMultiProject\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>C:\code\gradle-maven-transform\example\smallJavaMultiProject\target</directory>
    <finalName>project-1.0</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\code\gradle-maven-transform\example\smallJavaMultiProject\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\code\gradle-maven-transform\example\smallJavaMultiProject\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>C:\code\gradle-maven-transform\example\smallJavaMultiProject\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>C:\code\gradle-maven-transform\example\smallJavaMultiProject\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with a different solution in the end. Rather than accepting a single root `pom.xml` as input, I instead require a collection of `pom.xml` to be resolved. I also now embed the `maven-model-builder` and invoke the `DefaultModelBuilder` via a `DefaultModelBuildingRequest`

Eg:

```
DefaultModelBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultModelBuilderFactory();
DefaultModelBuilder builder = factory.newInstance();
ModelBuildingRequest req = new DefaultModelBuildingRequest();
req.setProcessPlugins(false);
req.setModelResolver(createModelResolver());
req.setValidationLevel(ModelBuildingRequest.VALIDATION_LEVEL_MINIMAL);
for (File pomFile : pomFiles) {
   req.setPomFile(pomFile);
   Model effectivePom = builder.build(req).getEffectiveModel();
   ...
}
```

Code [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-maven-transform/blob/master/plugin/src/main/groovy/com/lazan/maven/transform/PomTransform.java#L84) for anyone interested

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It doesn't even relate to the question.

Comment: Well... my ultimate goal is to have an effective pom for every pom.xml in a maven build. Since I've proven that `help:effective-pom` doesn't always do this from the root project my remaining choice was to call `help:effective-pom` for each `pom.xml`. I found a way of doing this without needing maven installed, via the maven APIs which is much quicker than invoking `mvn help:effective-pom` from the shell

Comment: I would appreciate if you could include more details about the `createModelResolver()` method, I do not understand how to instantiate a `ModelResolver`.

Comment: See [this search](https://github.com/search?q=user%3Auklance+ModelResolverImpl&type=code) of my github repo

Comment: While I have to agree with the others that this answer solves a different problem than what you have asked for in the question, it helped me so much with a problem that I was facing! Thanks!

Comment: My initial problem statement is "I want to generate an effective pom for all the subprojects in a multi-module build". This answer solves that problem

Answer (score 4):

The [EffectivePomMojo](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-help-plugin-2.2/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/help/EffectivePomMojo.java?revision=1448364&view=markup#l90) is an aggregator goal. Which means it's invoked only for the module that you run it for. But you're right that it should dump all the sub-projects as well. The reason it doesn't do this in your case is because of this line:

```
if ( projects.get( 0 ).equals( project ) && projects.size() > 1 )
```

In your case the upper-most project is last in the graph (because there are no dependencies on it from any other module). If you add it as a parent to project0 (and only for that module), then it'd put your root pom at the 1st position in the graph and everything will work as you expect.

I can't come up with a justification for this behaviour. So if you raise an issue in the bugtracker everyone will benefit :) Please update us if/when you get the answer.

PS: such questions are easy to solve if you know how to debug Maven plugins. For this you can use `mvnDebug` instead of `mvn` and then open plugin's source code and attach to the debug session.

Comment: Thanks for your input but unfortunately a bug fix doesn't help as it would require users of my utility to upgrade maven which I definitely don't want. I need something that "just works".

Comment: You don't actually need to upgrade Maven. Instead of the shortcut you can use the fully qualified plugin GAV which would use whichever version you specify: `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:effective-pom`

Comment: Interesting, I can do this from command line? Or need to put this in the `pom.xml`

Comment: In command line. You need to have plugins in pom.xml only if you want to bind them to phases like test, compile, package or if you want to pre-configure them.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev Any help  for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55530477/maven-pom-inheritance-ands-overriding-in-parent-child-module ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the `parent` element in each of your sub-modules `pom.xml` in addition to the `modules` elements in your root project such as:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.gradle.test.performance</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
```

Otherwise it won't be picked-up when you run `help:effective-pom` command.

EDIT: some precision as to why the plugin does not work with Aggregation. **Aggregation** (done with `modules` element) is different than **Inheritance** (using the `parent` element). However the plugin documentation clearly mentions:

> The effective-pom goal is used to make visible the POM that results
>   from the application of interpolation, inheritance and active
>   profiles.

And there is no mention of aggregated plugins. I believe it basically means:

> I will take the pom you are providing me, apply interpolation, inheritance and active profiles but NOT aggregation, and give you the resulting pom. Deal with it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, whilst this might make it work... there is no requirement in maven that sub modules in a multi-module build must inherit from a parent. The multi-module project builds perfectly fine in maven without inheritance. What would happen if some modules inherited from `parent1` and others inherited from `project2`? This is also a valid use case in maven?

Comment: From the doc: `The effective-pom goal is used to make visible the POM that results from the application of interpolation, inheritance and active profiles.` It mentions Inheritance, but with modules you are using Aggregation - that's different, and I think this behavior is then expected by the Help Plugin ;)
No, there is no requirement that aggregated modules such as yours also inherit from the same project. If some modules inherit from different parents but are aggregated together, that's a perfectly valid case, though it may not be regarded as best practice.

Comment: I've worked on many projects where the "aggregator" is not the parent (there's a separate project for the parent). So guessing this scenario won't work either. I was looking for a generic solution to get the effective pom for the "aggregate" of projects (ie the collection which is built via `mvn package`). Unfortunately it seems that `mvn help:effective-pom` can't do this generically. Think I'll investigate ModelBuilder as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4881362/1089967). Thanks again