# Determine parent pom of given pom through maven/Aether

Tags: java, maven, parent-pom, aether

Given a `pom.xml` file, what would be a reliable way to determine the GAV of the parent?

At the moment, I am parsing the XML, but this means that terms like `${some.number}` need to be resolved by hand.

Is there a Maven goal or an Aether method that determines the parent pom for a given `pom.xml`?

Comment: At what time do you want the information, and where is that being used?  Outside Maven?

Comment: Not during the build. I want to download a pom.xml from Nexus and then determine its parent.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838591/is-there-a-library-for-reading-maven2-3-pom-xml-files?

Comment: If something like `${...}` is given in the parent version or the version itself something is wrong..except they are `${revision}` etc. with Maven 3.5.+...Furthermore the question is: Are you parsing them from a repository or before/after the build?

Comment: I read them from a repository.

Comment: So there should never be placeholder in the version tag given otherwise the repository is broken!!

Comment: That is actually true. So it probably fine to read the information by parsing XML.