MavenProject coming null inside ITestContext
My end goal here is to read all pom.xml from different modules from a custom Testng listener which is present in one IntegrationTests module.
Expected behavior
iTestContext.getAttribute("maven.project") should not be null
Actual behavior
@Override
    public void onStart(final ITestContext iTestContext) {
        mavenProject = (MavenProject) iTestContext.getAttribute("maven.project");
        System.out.println("project found!!"+ mavenProject.getName());

mavenProject is coming as null
I am creating a custom TestNG listener and this is happening inside it.
public final class TestDataCollectListener implements IExecutionListener, ITestListener, ISuiteListener {

@Override
    public void onStart(final ITestContext iTestContext) {
        mavenProject = (MavenProject) iTestContext.getAttribute("maven.project");
        System.out.println("project found!!"+ mavenProject.getName());
}
}

What am I missing here. I even added maven-surefire-plugin but no change.
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                            <value>false</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>com.abc.test.pqr.TestDataCollectListener</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


Did you try the recommendations that I added in https://github.com/testng-team/testng/issues/3141#issuecomment-2187926480

@KrishnanMahadevan maven.project should be injected from maven automatically when running from maven-surefire-plugin. The properties which I want are not user defined but system properties which should be there.

Why do you need the information maven.project?

@khmarbaise My Testng listener should have access to pom.xml of current module and pom.xml of all other modules in my java repo.

@MehulParmar - Maven surefire plugin is NOT going to inject the Maven context into your execution. For you to be able to do that, you would perhaps need to extend maven surefire plugin itself wherein you bake this capability within it. If you are just interested in parsing pom files, then I would suggest that you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4838664/679824

@MehulParmar The question is why do you need that access to the pom and modules? Please explain what you are trying to achieve?

@khmarbaise I am trying to classify modules by reading their pom.xml. If the module's pom.xml has a certain plugin inside it, then it will be considered type A. If it doesn't have that particular maven plugin then its type B. I need this information for all modules, in my Testng plugin to call a certain API.

@khmarbaise any idea Any idea if maven-sirefire-plugin supports creatingMavenProject automatically?

First if you just read the pom.xml you can't imply based on existence of a plugin because plugin can be inherited? Do you have that in mind? Apart from what kind of  type is implied based on that? And no maven-surefire-plugin does not support create MavenProject... furthermore what's not clear to why you need the information in your Test? That sounds more like a task for Maven plugin ... Maybe you can give more details what of catogization you need to do and for what purpose so I could give a better answer/idea?

Another thought: Based on iTestContext.getAttribute("maven.project"); it requires to have injected somethow the information into that context which maven-surefire-plugin simply isn't doing.. You could read the pom.xml on your own...

The idea to use iTestContext.getAttribute("maven.project"); can not work (nor does maven-surefire-plugin anything like that, because you don't define in your test (see example excerpt from the docs https://testng.org/#_interceptors_for_data_providers)

@khmarbaise I am trying to calculate code coverage of all java modules from an API called inside Testng listener. That API need information which modules has a particular maven plugin A or not. Because in artifactory, the code is packaged as .class for A maven plugin modules and as jars for modules with no plugin A. So I need to read pom.xml of all modules from this TestNG listener.

Why do you try to do that on your own? You know JaCoCo exists?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
